# Regex in Javascript for places holder

Tags: javascript, regex

What the regex that match to both phrases?

{{logo}},{{tabs}}

I tried to use this: `{{.*}}` or `{{.}}` but not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'{{logo}},{{tabs}}'.match(/{{.*}}/g) // greedy
// ["{{logo}},{{tabs}}"]
'{{logo}},{{tabs}}'.match(/{{.*?}}/g) // non-greedy
// ["{{logo}}", "{{tabs}}"]
```